# How to put a scroll bar for one field of the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio

I designed my website home page using a table 
and I need to put a scroll bar in one field, yet I don't how to do so. So I'll put the html of that field.

```
<td colspan="4" style="background-position: center center; border: medium groove #FFFFFF; background-image: none; background-repeat: no-repeat;" rowspan="9">
                <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" CssClass="auto-style38" ForeColor="#333333" Width="1110px">
                    <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        Professor:
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pu") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        Title:
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tu") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        Body:<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("bu") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                </asp:DataList>
            </td>
```

Comment: You are not really asking a question. You need to elaborate.

Comment: basically I want to know how to add a scroll bar, as it is written in the "title" of my "question"

Comment: and I did put my html so that if any one knows maybe can help me putting it?